# z-index not working on several items?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web, z-index

I have a `select` box with 3 items that is positioned over an `input` textbox. When I open the `select` box, my `input` field overlaps the first `select` box `option` item.

I have set an inline style, `z-index:9999;` on the `select` box.
When I put `z-index:-1` on my `input` textbox, it moves behind the container `div` and is no longer clickable. If I put `z-index: -2` on the *container*, nothing happens. How do I resolve this issue?

Code Excerpt:

```
<div id="search-2" class="search-widget-wrapper widget_search">
    <div id="searchwrapper">
      <form method="get" id="searchform" action="#">
          <input type="text" class="searchbox" name="s" id="s" placeholder="search here &hellip;" />
          <input type="image" class="searchbox_submit" value="" />
      </form>
</div></div>

#searchwrapper {
    background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/responsive-icsl/images/search_box.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 11px 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 288px;
}
```

The container

```
<li class='lang'>
   <select id="lang-chooser" name="language-chooser" style="max-width:80px;" onChange = "document.location.href =this.value">
    <option value='localhost/?s=sidebar&amp;x=0&amp;y=0' selected='selected' title='./wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/flags/gb.png'> ENG </option>
    <option value='localhost/?s=sidebar&amp;x=0&amp;y=0&amp;lang=de' title='./wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/flags/de.png'> DEU </option>
    <option value='localhost/?s=sidebar&amp;x=0&amp;y=0&amp;lang=ru' title='./wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/flags/ru.png'> RUS </option>
   </select>
</li>
```

#### Update

i added a screenshot to show the problem:

screenshot: http://666kb.com/i/c7bv3x65hgkwj0gzs.jpg

actually, i use msdropdown, to render my dropdownbox, this will automatically make z-index:9999 on the dropdown.

my build up is this:

```
  <div id="header">
    <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <div id="logo">
        </div><!-- end of #logo -->  
    <div id="headermenuwrapper">            
   </div><!-- end of #headermenuwrapper -->
   <div id="headerwidgetswrapper">
       <div id="headernewswrapper">
       <div class="headernewstitle">NEWS</div>
       <div class="headernewsnav"></div>
       </div><!-- end of #headernewswrapper -->
       <div id="headersearchwrapper">
       </div><!-- end of #headersearchwrapper -->
    </div><!-- end of #headerwidgetswrapper -->
</div><!-- end of #header -->
```

Comment: it seems that it's on your localhost. don't you have it online to see what exactly happens there?

Comment: z-index is inherited from the parent, so you must put it on the element you wish to "bring to the front" and not its parent.

Comment: Please use something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your problem and then link to it in your question. The code you have provided isn't really enough to help us see the problem and actually seems pretty irrelevant as there isn't even any `z-index` values in there. We could take some educated guesses, but we'd rather give you something solid

Comment: Do you mean the `select#lang-choose` with "dropdown"? I don't see any `z-index` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a ground zero for your z-index

So like if you want one input behind and one infront of content

```
<div class="content" style="z-index:0;>
  <input type="text" style="z-index:-1;/>
  <input type="text" style="z-index:1;/>
</div>
```